# Writing DataFrame to csv file. Each Column in a seperate cell does not work. Delimitor does not do anything

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a Dataframe with 2 columns and 30 rows. I want to write it to a csv file but it always ends up writing my columns into one cell. Basically my Dataframe is 30x2 and my csv file is 30x1. I have tried every answer I found on stackoverlfow but nothing worked.

I have tried changing seperator from , to ; but nothing changed
currently it looks like this

```
        df_ts = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(file_name, timestamps_err)), columns=['FIle', 'Timestamp'])

        df_ts.to_csv('Results_test_data.csv',mode="a", sep=',', index=False)
```

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: Yes, some sample data would help. df.to_csv('Results_test_data.csv',mode="a", sep=',', index=False) seems to be working perfectly fine for me for a valid dataframe

Comment: I just solved it. For some reason it does not work with mode set to append. Will just leave it at write and will store the dataframes I create in a loop and write them all at once to the csv